# Saving webview content as Bitmap/Image

Tags: android, webview, android-canvas, android-bitmap

The application is having a webview, which shows some html data.
I'm trying to save this content as bitmap using below code

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(detailsView.getWidth(), detailsView.getHeight() , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
detailsView.draw(canvas);
```

This works well when the content is small.
 
But when it is large **webview** is showing it with scroll bars. and only the visible content is drawn to the bitmap.

How to force the hidden content to be added to the bitmap?

Is there any way to dynamically scroll the webview and fetch the hidden portions and add it to the bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first calling `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()`?